# Haskell - Map of functions that take the same map

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I am currently writing a programming language in Haskell. This programming language is similar to Factor, being a concatenative stack-based language. However, after getting quite far, I hit a brick wall: I have a Data.Map of type:

`Map.Map String ([YodaVal] -> YodaVal, Int)`

But I need the functions stored in the map to take the map as a parameter, so I can preserve environment when recursing, and also to possibly allow recursive function definitions, and recursive definitions of Haskell --> Yoda functions. However, the type would then look like:

`type Env = Map.Map String ([YodaVal] -> Env -> [YodaVal] -> YodaVal, Int)`
 Which of course expands to:

`Map.Map String ([YodaVal] -> Map.Map String ... -> [YodaVal] -> YodaVal, Int)`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? - I think there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Here is the conventional way of implementing an interpreter in Haskell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970431/implementing-a-language-interpreter-in-haskell See the "Evaluating Expressions" section. How about doing it that way?

Comment: @user5402, yeah, i was thinking there must be. I'm sorry if my question was not clear, but the above type is the type of my variable envirnoment. I want to be able to pass the current variable environment into the functions in that variable envirnoment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can describe infinite types with a `newtype`:

```
newtype Env = Env {getEnv :: Map String ([Val] -> Env -> [Val] -> Val, Int))}
```

This will typecheck, and the runtime representation will be as if there were no wrapper.